# vAlign element in center, but in a horizontal position relative to content

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/DAFHq/1/

```
<div id="gray-box">
<div id="red-box"></div>
</div>
```

I need the RED square to be positioned 20px to the right of the gray box with scrolling content in it, while keeping it vertically aligned in the center.

It should remain positioned relative to the gray box while scrolling and when the screen is resized.

Any ideas? The jsFiddle is one I found and modified to show what I need, The vertical align is perfect, but I have no idea howto position it how I need it horizontally.

Maybe something with jQuery?

Comment: What grey box? There isn't one in your example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yeah jsFiddle messed up. Ive updated the link now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var positionFoo = function() {
  $('#foo').css({
    'left': $('#bar').offset().left + $('#bar').width() + 20 + 'px',
    'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - ($('#foo').height() / 2)
  });
};

$(window).resize(positionFoo);
positionFoo();
```

You will also need to add `position: fixed;` to `#Foo`.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/DAFHq/5/)

Answer (score 1):

you need an holder element for the scrolling elements.

```
<div id="grey-box">
    <div id="red-box"></div>
    <div id="elements-holder"></div>
</div>

.elements-holder {
    overflow: auto;
}

#grey-box {
    position: relative;
}

#red-box {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px; 
}
```

Comment: yeah.. I thought someone would suggest that, thats not an option. The pages contents, in this case the graybox must scroll normally in the whole broswer window.